# Inserting PHP variables into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a small game to pass time in PHP, and for that, I use a database in MySQL. But, everytime that I check on if it inserted the variables into the database, it doesn't show up. 

This is the query that I'm using:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO `Users`
    (
        Username, 
        Class, 
        Level, 
        Health, 
        Max_Health, 
        Mana, 
        Max_Mana, 
        Intelligence, 
        Strength, 
        Dexitery, 
        Endurance, 
        Vitality, 
        Experience, 
        Required_Experience, 
        Gold, 
        Equiped_Armor, 
        Equiped_Weapon, 
        Inventory_Slot1, 
        Amount1, 
        Inventory_Slot2, 
        Amount2, 
        Inventory_Slot3, 
        Amount3, 
        Inventory_Slot4, 
        Amount4, 
        Inventory_Slot5, 
        Amount5, 
        Inventory_Slot6, 
        Amount6, 
        Inventory_Slot7, 
        Amount7, 
        Inventory_Slot8, 
        Amount8, 
        Inventory_Slot9, 
        Amount9, 
        Inventory_Slot10, 
        Amount10, 
        Skill_1, 
        Skill_2, 
        Skill_3, 
        Skill_4, 
        Skill_5, 
        Skill_6, 
        Skill_7, 
        Location
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
        ".$Username.", 
        ".$Class.", 
        ".$Level.", 
        ".$Health.", 
        ".$Max_Health.", 
        ".$Mana.", 
        ".$Max_Mana.", 
        ".$Intelligence.", 
        ".$Strength.", 
        ".$Dexitery.", 
        ".$Endurance.", 
        ".$Vitality.", 
        ".$Experience.", 
        ".$Req_Experience.", 
        ".$Gold.", 
        ".$Equiped_Armor.", 
        ".$Equiped_Weapon.", 
        ".$Inventory_Slot1.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot2.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot3.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot4.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot5.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot6.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot7.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot8.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot9.", 
        0, 
        ".$Inventory_Slot10.", 
        0, 
        ".$Skill_1.", 
        ".$Skill_2.", 
        ".$Skill_3.", 
        ".$Skill_4.", 
        ".$Skill_5.", 
        ".$Skill_6.", 
        ".$Skill_7.", 
        'Town'
    )";
mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong, so some help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Echo the query out just before you try to insert it with `echo $sql;` and see which variable is empty. This is the most likely cause unless you are doing something wrong with your query/connection.

Comment: you're doing several things wrong within this single line of code : use of `mysl_`, code open to SQL Injection, bad syntax, typos in your field names ("Dexitery" ?), apparently a very bad data model, ... If you want to make your time usefull, try and learn from the start to use the best practices !

Comment: Probably your php variables contain strings which you did not put in quotes. Tough even if that solves your problem, that single SQL already shows up major issues with you code. The `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`, you should also use prepared statemnts and also such a wide tables points to a poor database design.

Answer (score 1):

You can try echoing out the query in PHP before executing it.

```
echo $query;
```

You can then run the echoed out query in your mysql shell or phpmyadmin to see why it isn't getting executed.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer. It is the right thing to do, but isn't a solution to the problem.

Comment: Ya. Sorry for that. Will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the values on your query
 to something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Users`(Username, Class, Level) VALUES ('$Username', '$Class', '$Level');
```

Comment: There do indeed appear to be string values that will need quotes in the insert.

Answer (score 1):

'Probably it's because of capitalized column names (ex. **U** sername). Type those names in grave accents `` ` ``

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `Users`(`Username`, `Class`, ...
```

also variables other than numerical should be in quotes

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Users`(`Username`, `Class`, ..., `Map`) 
VALUES ('".$Username."', '".$Class."', ... , '".$Map."')";
```

Comment: None of the column names are [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in the query, so no need for backticks.

Comment: The problem is not a column name using Reserved Words but column name which is using capitalized column names - like I wrote in my answer. I've faced that once.

Comment: I didn't downvote as the caps could maybe be right, but if that is the case, you still don't need to backtick them - just get the column names right :)